# Вопрос по unity в C# касательно объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне надо в скрипт засунуть Текст который лежит в другой сцене. Как это возможно сделать? GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag не работает, как можно найти Текст?

Comment: Это не имеет смысла. Unity уничтожает объекты сцены, когда загружает новую. Так что даже если Вы как-то найдете этот текст, он всегда будет null...

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше всего использовать PlayerPrefs

Answer (score 2):

Вам помогут статические переменные, если не поймёте моё объяснение, то погуглите.

Сохраните текст в скрипте в статичную переменную string (static public string;). Потом в другом скрипте, в котором вам нужно, получите значение статической переменной и сохраните её в другую переменную.

То есть вот первый скрипт, где мы задаём значение переменной, пусть скрипт будет называться ScriptOne:

```
static public string myText;
void Start()
{
myText = "Text";
}
```

Вот второй скрипт, где мы получаем значение:

```
public string myNewText;
void Start
{
myNewText = ScriptOne.myText //названия скрипта, где находится статическая переменная; точка; название переменной.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте PlayerPrefs

В скрипте, в котором вам нужно сохранить делайте это:

```
string g;

void Start(){
PlayerPrefs.SetString("key",g); // первое значение - это ключ, он может быть любым, второе значение это переменная
}
```

Далее вы можете в любой другой сцене получить сохраняем текст, для этого введите это:

```
 string g = PlayerPrefs.GetString("key") //название ключа
```